# How to fix "macOS needs to repair your library to run applications" after High Sierra upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, error, high-sierra, repair, library

After upgrading to High Sierra, I'm getting this error message about 30-50 times a day:

[image]

Is there any way to find out what is causing this error?  Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

So none of the given answers works on High Sierra (OS X 10.16.x) and I don't have Clean My Mac 3. This Apple article did the trick for me and pretty easily: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538.

This involves setting the permissions through the finder and then resetting the permissions by using the command

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

Make sure you cd to the appropriate home folder (I did this logged in as myself for another user that was experiencing the issue) to avoid access errors.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, just a little information: `id -u` gives currently logged in user's id.

Comment: FYI This worked on Mojave as well. 
We had started getting "MacOS needs to repair your Library to run applications" error messages. Files disappeared from the desktop, and many applications has a slash through them (no permission to run.) Disk Utilities didn't fix it, and neither did running repairHomePermissions in Recovery Mode. Nor did reinstalling Mojave. These are all things worth trying in general, but `diskutil resetUserPermissions \ <uid>` is what fixed it for us.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed my problem.

To set the permissions on your user folder as giving you access/ownership:

```
sudo chown -R <user> ~/Library
sudo chgrp -R <groupname> ~/Library
```

You get the your username by running:

```
id -u
```

You get your group by running:

```
id -g
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  With the goal of writing a clear and concise answer, please take a look at a few things:  1)  How is *your* problem related to the OP's?  2)  How does one determine their username and groupname?  3)  How does this address the OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

1.)

- Open disc Utility and select you Systemdrive, run First Aid.
- Restart

If this step doesn't work, try the second

2.)

- Restart, press <kbd>CMD + R</kbd> to boot into recovery
- Next, choose **Terminal** from the Utilities menu
- Type `resetpassword`
- Select your Systemdrive (e.g. Macintosh HD/SSD)
- Select your Username from the list
- Click on Reset Home folder Permissions and ACL's button
- Reboot and logged in your Account and see that your problem is repaired.
- Sometimes you need to run reset permissions a second time until it works.

**You don't need both steps, if one works, you're done.**

Comment: This seems outdated; on the new version of the OS, it doesn't have any such option.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem lies with Permissions, yet High Sierra (10.13.3) has removed access to 'Repair Permissions' in Disk Utility.

A neat way round this is to use CleanMyMac3. In addition to its basic role of cleaning unwanted files from your Mac, it has an option of Maintenance which offers 'Repair Permissions'. This took just a few seconds on my 13" MBP and the problem is solved – no hassle, no use of Terminal.
I'm mighty impressed with this program.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem for many days.  After upgrading to Mojave. 
Disk utility repair was only a temporary fix.
Then finally found this link. It did the trick. 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538 
Essentially, resetting user permissions.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. While multiple (and also similar) answers are totally fine please try to provide additional value if you basically post a link which has already been mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Also...Apple links are notorious for going stale making the link-only answer useless in the future.  It's best to put the key points here and supply the link for reference.